# send_data or send_file(ruby) not working in safari browser?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, safari

I used following code to send or downlaod file at client's browser.
That is perfectly working in all browser BUT in safari after clicking on link when i refresh the page it makes my session nil.

def export_csv

csv = CSV.generate(:force_quotes => true) do |line|
      line <<["Employee Code", "Name", "Status", "Skills"]
    end

```
send_data csv,
  :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
  :disposition => "attachment; filename=EmployeeSkillsData-#{Time.now.strftime('%d-%m-%y--%H-%M')}.csv"
```

end

I tried this code with some other application also but result is same.
Please help to resolve this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
send_data csv,
  :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
  :disposition => "inline",  # optional
  :filename=>"EmployeeSkillsData-#{Time.now.strftime('%d-%m-%y--%H-%M')}.csv"
```